# How to make vertically scrollable text area?

Tags: html, css, scroll, textarea

I have a `textarea` html element, which may contain URLs. User should be able to click on such URLs to open them. Currently the code looks like below:

```
<textarea rows="26" class="form-control" disabled> {{ text|urlize }}</textarea>
```

Of course, links are not supported there currently. Looks like the `textarea` should be replaced with something else. I've tried to use `div` instead, but I am not sure how to restrict its height (for `textarea` I used `rows="26"`) and make it scrollable.

Comment: Can't understand your question, what do you mean by clicking a link from a text area ?

Comment: @AbdelrahmanWahdan, looks at this fiddlet - http://jsfiddle.net/and7ey/o4zLap5r/ - you can not just click on the example.com to open it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

please check this code

**html**

```
<div class="textarea"> </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.textarea{
  width:50%;
  background-color:#eee;
  overflow:hidden;
  height:250px;
  max-height:250px;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KpYOKq